# Facebook redirect buton

Tags: redirect, facebook, buttons

In this post, [Facebook like button that redirects?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/24517/facebook-like-button-that-redirects), I saw a code to redirect after doing a Facebook "like".

I pasted in there, but I can't figure out how to put the link I want to redirect to?

Comment: I see you did not comment on Ottos answer, perhaps you should have asked for clarification rather than starting a whole new question

Comment: @TomJNowell New users cannot comment.

Answer (score 0):

If you got everything else running and it is really just the redirect that you can't manage, then replace the 'alert' lines in Ottos example with `window.location = "http://www.your-domain.tld/"`.